# Why the macro doesn't work?

Tags: macros, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Here is the macro, whcih, for some reason, doesn't work:

```
[
    { "command": "split_selection_into_lines" },
    { "command": "move_to", args: {"to": "hardeol"} },
    { "command": "move_to", args: {"to": "hardbol", "extend": true} },
]
```

I can do the same things via plugin, but I don't like to use it here:

```
import sublime_plugin
class SplitIntoLinesReverseCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
        self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "hardeol"})
        self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "hardbol", "extend": True})
```

Why the macro doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro doesn't work because the JSON that you're using to define it is invalid; the `args` key needs to be wrapped in double quotes, but it's not. As a result the Macro won't load and thus can't execute.

If your color scheme supports it, the invalid characters will be highlighted to indicate the problem for you.

A corrected version would be:

```json
[
    { "command": "split_selection_into_lines" },
    { "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol"} },
    { "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardbol", "extend": true} },
]
```